# Extend angular service worker (ngsw-worker.js)

Tags: angular8, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

I want to extend native service worker for angular pwa.
Task:
change all base fetched urls (called origin in sw)
It needs for mirrors - on url for all mirrors in sw.
I have tried to register custom sw via copy ngsw-worker.js and extend it,
but it broke config and updating mechanism for sw (because i have to disable default serviceworker flag in angular.json for exclude default ngsw-worker.js file usage).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Viktor Kolomiets. Please, consider adding some code. It will make it easier for people to help you. For more information, please take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: there is no need a code. Its default module of angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceWorkerModule.register('custom-ngsw.js', {enabled: true, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately'})

just pass another file and copy whole code from sw.
also files can be merged via importScripts('some.js');